# Combine multiple rows into one row in R

Tags: r, dataset

I am creating a sample of 3 observations with 3 values. I would like to then combine them into one observation and determine the frequency of duplicate values but would like to know what values are duplicated how many times. For example, "59741111" is duplicated 3 times and "29611022" is duplicated twice. Thank you very much.

```
set.seed(10231995)

df <- t(replicate(3, sample(id, 3, replace=FALSE, prob=NULL)))
df
```

Result
     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] "59741111" "73380703" "29611022"
[2,] "59741111" "70470420" "59741111"
[3,] "33360105" "29611022" "32080517"

Desired result

[,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]       [,8]       [,9]
"59741111" "73380703" "29611022" "59741111" "70470420" "59741111" "33360105" "29611022" "32080517"

Value                freq     rel freq

"59741111"             3        .33

"29611022"             2        .22

Comment: The native `R` function for doing this is `table`.  There is also a `duplicated` function you can use (with some post-processing).

Answer (score 1):

The "id" variable is not defined in your reproducible example, so I cannot run your code as is. However, I can still help you out. Take a look at the code below:

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(10231995)


id <- 1:5
df <- data.table(t(replicate(3, sample(id, 3, replace=FALSE, prob=NULL))))
df

df2 <- melt(df)
df2

df2[, .N, by=value]
```

[image]

The data.table package in R lets you do a lot of "SQL-like" operations which are what you would be looking for to do these "group-by" calculations to calculate frequency of duplicates, etc.

This [data.table tutorial](https://www.r-bloggers.com/intro-to-the-data-table-package/) provides a good introduction into how to do these calculations and it explains briefly their syntax.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question, whose output is supposed to tabulate frequencies of duplicate values.

Comment: You are right, i misread this.. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer to actually answer their qeustion - thanks for catching it!